# Memory leak and/or data persistence in dask distributed

Tags: multiprocessing, distributed, dask

I'm using dask/distributed to submit 100+ evaluations of a function to the multi-node cluster. Each eval is very costly, about 90 sec of CPU time. I've noticed though that there seems to be a memory leak and all workers over time grow in size, although the function i'm evaluating is not pure.
Here's sample code to reproduce this behavior:

```
import numpy as np
from dask.distributed import Client

class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = np.random.rand(2000, 2000)  # dummy data, not really used

    @staticmethod
    def myfun1(k):
        return np.random.rand(10000 + k, 100)

    def myfun2(self, k):
        return np.random.rand(10000 + k, 100)

client = Client('XXX-YYY:8786')
f = Foo()
tasks = client.map(f.myfun2, range(100), pure=False)
results = client.gather(tasks)
tasks = []
```

If client.map() is called to execute f.myfun1() (which is just a static method), the workers don't grow in size. However, if one calls f.myfun2() workers size grows considerably (eg. 50mb -> 400mb) after just one client.map() call above. Also client.close() does nothing to reduce workers size.

Is this a memory leak or I'm not using dask.distributed correctly? I definitely don't care about results of my calculations being available afterwards or shared on the cluster. FWIW, tested with distributed v1.19.1 and Python 3.5.4

Comment: Did you ever got an answer for this?

Answer (score 1):

Nice example.

Your `myfun2` method is attached to your `f = Foo()` object, which carries around with it a decently large attribute `(f.a)`.  This `f.myfun2` method is thus actually really expensive to move around, and you're creating 1000 of them.  If you can it's best to avoid using methods of large objects in a distributed setting.  Instead consider using functions.

Comment: Thanks Matthew. The problem here is really not the cost of moving that data around, but what happens after calculation... i.e. obervations that all workers size/footprint increases considerably over time (that's why i asked about possible memory-leak?). The only way to fix it has been to run client.restart() periodically but that resets the entire cluster.

So if my goal is just to submit an expensive/long calculation to a worker without the need to share data/results between workers, is there a better way to do this and also to clear/reset worker state after single calc?